# Dúvida com contador em loop for

Tags: python, loop, for

Quero rodar este loop bem simples:

```
for i in range (1, 5):
    num = int(input("Digite um numero positivo: "))
    if (num < 0):
        print("Você digitou um número negativo, tente de novo.")
```

Caso o usuário digite um número negativo, quero que este "palpite" não seja adicionado no contador `i`, ou seja, quero subtrair 1 de `i` para que o palpite não seja contabilizado.

Já tentei colocar `i = i -1` abaixo do meu `if` mas isso não altera o valor de `i` do meu contador.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não precisa manipular o valor de `i`. Basta fazer um *loop* infinito, e só interrompê-lo quando o número for positivo:

```
for i in range (1, 5):
    while True:
        num = int(input("Digite um numero positivo: "))
        if (num < 0):
            print("Você digitou um número negativo, tente de novo.")
        else: break
```

O `while True` roda "para sempre", e só é interrompido pelo `break`, que por sua vez só é chamado quando o número não é negativo.

Depois que o `while` é interrompido, o `for` continua para a próxima iteração.

Comment: Muito obrigado resolveu meu problema.